# Dash datatable active_cell

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to make my table interactive with my Mapbox using active cell.
In my data table, when I click on the cell it supposes to show me the signification points of the Lat and Log on the map. However, it shows me the error of

> “TypeError: update_graphs() missing 1 required positional argument: ‘active_cell’”

Heres my code for mapbox:

```
    import dash
    import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
    import dash_core_components as dcc
    import dash_html_components as html
    import pandas as pd
    import dash_table
    from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
    from engine import session
    from model import Table1
    import plotly.express as px
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
    mapbox_access_token = "my token map"
    df = pd.read_sql(session.query(Table1).statement,session.bind)
    fig=go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
            lat=['1.11','1.22','1.33'],
            lon=['101.12','101.22','102.54'],
            mode='markers',
            marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
                size=10,
              color='rgb(255, 0, 0)'
            ),
            text=["1","2","3"]
        ))
    fig.update_layout(
        autosize=True,
        hovermode='closest',
        mapbox=dict(
            accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
            bearing=0,
            center=dict(
                lat=1.222,
                lon=103.856
            ),
            pitch=0,
            zoom=2
        ),
    )
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP], suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='testtable',
                    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i,
                              'deletable': False,  
                              'renamable': True  
                              } for i in df.columns],
                    data=df.to_dict('records'),  
                    #details design of my table which is slighty long#
                    )]),
                dcc.Graph(figure=fig3_6,id='selectgraph'),

      @app.callback(
        Output('selectgraph', 'figure'),
        Input('testtable', 'active_cell'),
        Input('testtable', 'selected_row_ids'))
    def update_graphs(row_ids,selected_row_ids,active_cell):
        selected_id_set = set(selected_row_ids or [])
    
        if row_ids is None:
            dff = df3_6
            row_ids = df3_6['id']
        else:
            dff = df3_6.loc[row_ids]
    
        active_row_id = active_cell['row_id'] if active_cell else None
        colors = ['#FF69B4' if id == active_row_id
                  else '#7FDBFF' if id in selected_id_set
        else '#0074D9'
                  for id in row_ids]
        return [
            dcc.Graph(
                id=column + '--row-ids',
                figure=fig3_6,
                mode='markers',
                marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
                    size=2,
                color=colors,
                ))
        for column in ['long','lat'] if column in dff
     ]
```

Thank you for reading my code, any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: The problem is that active_cells is not being defined, therefore it can not be used in the function which required it as a positional argument.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for ur feedback! I would like to ask how can I define my active_cell? is there any example that I can refer to? as I am fairly new to dash...

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code?

Comment: sure thing, I have edited to the rest of my code. Thank you!

Comment: I don't completely understand the purpose of the active_cell and where you are getting it from, so could you explain that to me?

Comment: Hi, so I got the active_cell coding from https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/interactivity . My plan was to click on the cell and it will show me the lat and lon on the map

Comment: After looking at your code more closely, and trying to figure out the problem, I couldn't find it by the eye test, but you can try and remove the  suppress_callback_exceptions=True, which could help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: ok I will do that, thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two inputs in the callback function, than the arguments of the inside function must be two. You have three arguments so it is not possible to retrieve the third. Try to rewrite the code with the function like this

```py
def update_graphs(active_cell,selected_row_ids):
```

In the same order of the inputs, and then reorganize the code.